# Class of algebras defined by quasi-identities is not closed under taking the quotients

Tags: examples-counterexamples, universal-algebra

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an algebra (in the sense of universal algebra) of some signature $\Sigma$. By *quasi-identity* I mean the formula of the form

$$(\forall x_1) (\forall x_2) \dots (\forall x_n) \left(\left[\bigwedge_{i=1}^{k}t_i(x_1, \dots, x_n)=s_i(x_1, \dots, x_n)\right]\rightarrow t(x_1, \dots, x_n)=s(x_1, \dots, x_n) \right) \;, $$

where $t_i(x_1, \dots, x_n), s_i(x_1, \dots, x_n), t(x_1, \dots, x_n), s(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ are terms (using the algebra operations) with all its variables among $x_1, \dots, x_n$.

Since the class of all algebras (of the considered signature) satisfying some quasi-identity is (allegedly) not a variety in general and clearly such class is closed under taking subalgebras and products, it follows that it is not closed under taking quotients in general.

So the question is:

**Is there some (possibly elementary) example of an algebra satisfying some quasi-identity and its quotient where the quasi-identity does not hold?**

My only idea was to show this for the cancellation law in some monoid, but I do not see any example (mainly because I do not see how the quotients look like).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea was correct. Take the cancellation law in a commutative monoid. It is satisfied by $\mathbb N$ but not by its quotient $(\{0, 1\}, +)$ (obtained by identifying all positive numbers to $1$). In this latter monoid, you have $0 + 1 = 1 = 1 + 1$, but $0 \not= 1$.

Comment: So the congruence has classes $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, right?

Comment: Right. In general, the quotients of $\mathbb{N}$ are of the form $\{0, 1, ..., t, t+ 1 , t + r-1\}$ where the congruence classes are $\{0\}$, ..., $\{t-1\}$, $\{t + nr \mid n \geqslant 0\}$, $\{t + 1 + nr \mid n \geqslant 0\}$, ..., $\{t + r-1 + nr \mid n \geqslant 0\}$, which corresponds to the congruence generated by $t = t + r$.

Answer (score 6):

The quasi-identity $\forall x(x+x=0\to x=0)$ holds in $\mathbb Z$ but not in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of seeing this about cancellation is to notice that free semigroups/monoids are cancellative, and every semigroup/monoid is a quotient of one.