# Do homomorphisms preserve order of subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I read that the only possible homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_7$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is the one mapping all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ to $\{0\}$. Since if there is another homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_7$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, it must be able to map any non-trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_7$, to a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$. However, this means that $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ would have a subgroup of order $7$, which is impossible.

I guess what is implied in the above statement is that homomorphisms preserve the order of subgroups ... but is this true in general ?

Comment: No, in general if $\phi : G \to G'$ is a homomorphism and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $|\phi(H)|$ is a divisor of $|H|$ but need not equal $|H|$. This follows, for example, from the [first isomorphism theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FirstGroupIsomorphismTheorem.html)

Comment: More generally, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766523/examples-of-properties-not-preserved-under-homomorphism) on "properties nor preserved under homomorphisms".

Comment: Indeed, $|\phi(H)|=[H:H\cap\ker\phi]$, so $\left.\phi\right|_H$ is $1$-to-$1$ iff $H\cap\ker\phi$ is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true in general. Let  $f: \mathbb Z_6 \to \mathbb Z_6$ given by $f(x)=2x$. The map $f$ is clearly a homomorphism but it does not preserve the order of the group itself.

I think this statement means, since only subgroups of $\mathbb Z_7$ are $\{0\}$ and the group itself, kernel of any non-trivial homomorphism is $\{0\}$ and so any non-trivial homomorphism is injective. This means $\mathbb Z_7$ is isomorphic to image of itself but this cannot happen since image of a homomorphism is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_{12}$ and this group does not have a subgroup of order $7$.